# Como pegar o estado do toggleButton Android?

Tags: android, button, widget, toggle

Como pegar o estado do `ToggleButton` se esta ligado ou desligado, olhei a documentação do Android só tem o método de mudar o estado, precisava pegar o estado do botão pra fazer a comparação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o método é o isChecked(). Ele é herdado da classe CompoundButton.

Ex:

```
if(myToggleButton.isChecked())
  // Faça algo se estiver checado
else
  // Faça algo se não estiver checado
```